# error in finding directory/path in including spout library

Tags: php, excel

I am using spout library to import excel data into mysql using php but I am having error in finding directory. I searched a lot but did not find any relevant stuff.

> Warning: require_once(here is your path of spout
>   library/spout-2.4.3/src/Spout/ Autoloader/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uploadexcel.php on line 23

![1]:( https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLspH.png)

Comment: can you paste your error message here?

Comment: ... and your code. We can't tell you where the problem with the code might be if we can't read it.